Create variable Date
I want to create a variable Date from 3 variables in my dataframe : 

data <- data %>%
    mutate(Z49= if_else(
        !is.na(Z49j) & !is.na(Z49m) & !is.na(Z49a) & Z49j != "" & Z49m != "" & Z49a != "",
        dmy(paste0(Z49j, "-", Z49m, "-", Z49a)),
        NA_Date_
    ))

It return this error : Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

I used as.Date( paste0(Z49a, "-", Z49m, "-", Z4ja)but it doesnt work and it return the same error

Please dput() (a sample of) your data.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Try Reduce.
> Reduce(\(x, y) paste0(x, '-', y), c(2024, 06, 27)) |> as.Date()
[1] "2024-06-27"

In data.frame:
> dat |>
+   transform(date=as.Date(Reduce(\(x, y) paste0(x, '-', y), 
+                                 list(year, month, day))))
           x year month day       date
1  0.1267466 2022     1  13 2022-01-13
2 -0.7880505 2023     2  14 2023-02-14
3 -0.3570466 2024     3  15 2024-03-15

However, ISO.date() might prevent from reinventing the steel:
> dat |>
+   transform(date=as.Date(do.call('ISOdate', list(year, month, day))))
           x year month day       date
1  0.1267466 2022     1  13 2022-01-13
2 -0.7880505 2023     2  14 2023-02-14
3 -0.3570466 2024     3  15 2024-03-15


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(x = c(0.126746646664235, -0.788050493294495, -0.357046622964776
), year = 2022:2024, month = 1:3, day = 13:15), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


thank you, but it return an error : Reduce(function(x, y) paste0(x, '-', y), c(lots[[lot_a_traiter]]$Z49a, lots[[lot_a_traiter]]$Z49m, lots[[lot_a_traiter]]$Z49j)) %>% as.Date()
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

@Alif Use a list, see update.

thank you, i use this :   mutate(
Z49 = case_when(
Z49j!= "" & Z49m!= "" & Z49a!= "" ~ as.Date(paste0(Z49a, "-", Z49m, "-", Z49j), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
TRUE ~ NA_Date_
), ... so I think tant I have to impose 'format'
